# Css looks totally the same, what triggered bottom menu button content diappearing?

Tags: css

This case is relatively complicated 
to be reproduce in jsfiddle so i posted a pair of urls for comparison:

(no issue version) template demo url: [click here](http://designingmedia.com/html/fbar/?theme=iCommerce-Prestashop)

the version which has issue url: (i've removed the link since it's solved)

(The weird thing is that By browser inspect element, when browser width<1170px , any click on the ".cd-nav-trigger" button on the bottom-left side, the menu will not expand as the demo template effect.

I guess it's only a css problem, but i didn't see any difference in their css stylings.

[image]

Failed in width<1170px

[image]

//The js function part

```
 //open or close the menu clicking on the bottom "menu" link
$('.cd-nav-trigger').on('click', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('menu-is-open');
    //we need to remove the transitionEnd event handler (we add it when scolling up with the menu open)
    mainNavigation.off('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend').toggleClass('is-visible');

});

// css media queries related with 1170px 
media="all"
@media only screen and (min-width: 1170px){
.is-fixed .cd-nav-trigger {
visibility: visible;
-webkit-transition: all 0s;
-moz-transition: all 0s;
transition: all 0s;
-webkit-transform: scale(1);
-moz-transform: scale(1);
-ms-transform: scale(1);
-o-transform: scale(1);
transform: scale(1);
-webkit-animation: cd-bounce-in .3s linear;
-moz-animation: cd-bounce-in .3s linear;
animation: cd-bounce-in .3s linear;
}

}
```

---

One answer below is able to fix this, but after deeper inspecting , i was wondering why the 
template demo dcmegameu.css file is exactly the same with the issue site. so the current anwser may not be the root cause, however, it did pointed out why it disappeared. 
[image]
the template dcmegamenu.css line 53 is same with issue site dcmegamenu.css

Comment: r u sure you have all the css files and required scripts are loaded?

Comment: @tarzanbappa for your reference
as in width>1170px all function and css working normally in this case.
and js function triggers change the classes exactly the same in all res. assuming there are related js scripts not loading the menu won't function in all cases. and by using IDE theme css folder comparison method, highlighting result also shows no directly related css styling changes within the above ".cd-nav-trigger' parent container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In dcmegamenu.css, you have this rule:

```
.dd-category-item {
    display: none;
}
```

That means that any element with the class `dd-category-item` will be hidden.  The only reason it's showing on wider screens is because there's a css query for screen width greater than 1170 pixels that has a different `display` set that is applied.

In general, the css for this site looks kind of disorganized and difficult to work with, as there are a lot of contradictory rules and `!important` modifiers applied.  This tends to make troubleshooting css issues difficult, as you've seen.

Comment: very sharp to solve it so fast. Since this site is prev customized css by another guy without mentioning which part has been changed, so it took me more time to investigate. no wonder I didn't find it, this styling is out of the theme folder css. thanks @recursive